# Excel: #reference fix for updated pivot tabel

Tags: excel, reference, pivot

I have a pivot table that gets its data from a column's values in a table. In that column, I have a formula which categorizes the data-lines depending on content. The pivot only sums up the occurrences of each category.

I then have a simple formula that references some data in the pivot table with the getdatapivot function.

The problem is now, that I get a reference-error if a category is not present in the data table. How do I avoid that?

Best regards

/Jacob

Comment: I could of cause put in an IFERROR function infront of every getpivotdata function, but that seems a bit like overkill or is that the only way to fix this?

Comment: You can edit your question to include additional information rather than posting it as a comment. Also, it'd help if you could post the relevant part of your worksheet either as a screenshot or a table.

Comment: What are you doing with the GETPIVOTDATA function output? Using it for additional calculations? Do you effectively want to turn those reference error GETPIVOTDATA output with zeros, so that any calculations that include them still work?